# Resource (png) size changes in main bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, resources, bundle

I have a `.png` resource in my XCode `iOS project`. I build and run the project on device. But when I looked in the project's bundle with an iPhone explorer, I saw that the size of the .png file had changed in device bundle (increased little). This doesn't happen on simulator.

In my application, I check the `MD5` value of that .png resource to understand if it's changed or not. So, this issue becomes critical for me.

I'm using `XCode 4.01` with iPhone 4.0 Simulator and a 4.3.3 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `Compress PNG Files` option in project settings to NO to disable compressing.